# Moving from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python

Currently I do all of my web-based programming in PHP, and each day I get more and more anxious to try Python.

Not that I haven't played with it in an interpreter, but I mean really, write a web-based project in Python, and possibly move pretty much exclusively over to Python.

But, I know that Python isn't strictly a web-based programming language (which is **awesome**) which makes me wonder if there are any hoops to jump through to use it on the web.

A simple example would be, that I'm sure there's no `$_POST` like variables in Python by default. How does functionality like that find its way into Python?

How do I move from PHP to Python smoothly? How do I use Python on the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is unlike PHP executed by a CGI like interface. This interface has an API to such variables.

Frameworks like [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) incorporate that API. It's recommended to use such a framework which makes a lot of things easier.

Comment: I'm looking into Django and other frameworks now, can you give an example of how the CGI interface can be used by Python minus a framework though?

Comment: There are more then one interface. You have FastCGI and WSGI and even mod_python which is an apache module like php.

Comment: mod_python is *not* like mod_php, other than the fact that it embeds an interpreter into httpd. mod_python is not for running Python apps via httpd, but rather to extend httpd using Python code. The difference may seem trivial, but is *very* important.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some [other web frameworks](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) web framework.

Answer (score 2):

Many [web frameworks](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) exist for Python, such as Django, werkzeug, etc. If you want to get "closer to the metal" then look into [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with PHP, except that it's not Python.
So it's not Pythonic!

If you often have to go between the Python world and the PHP world
(WordPress, Drupal, or other PHP framework), you can feel my pains for
not being able to use tons and tons of native Python libraries with ease,
such as [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), Machine Learning,
Deep Learning such as TensorFlow, etc.

PHP frameworks such as WordPress do offer xml-rpc, wp-api, wp-cli,
and other APIs to interface with Python and other languages.
However, preparing Python programs for such APIs and having PHP to
interface with the API on the other end is error prone, not robust,
costly to API client and Web server in terms of CPU and Memory just
for the sake of packing, transmitting, and unpacking for the API,
hard to troubleshoot on both ends of the API, and not scalable.
Hence, enterprises, web, or big-data applications cannot rely on those APIs
for high-speed and high-volume Web applications and large scale data sets.

So comes `pyx.php` to PHP-to-Python programmers' rescue!  (I wrote this.)

### Why convert from PHP to Python?

If you ask this question, you probably shouldn't use `pyx.php`.

`pyx.php` is a Cython compiled module that you can use to convert or
translate 99% of most common PHP source codes to pure Python.
In another words, it is a PHP-to-Python syntax emulation library in Cython.

The converted Python codes only require a Python 3.x interpreter,
the modules in the pyx repository, and some standard Python libraries.
PHP interpreter is not needed at all.

If we have already translated most of the WordPress core and other
scripts from PHP to Python using `pyx.php`, you can convert almost
any PHP code into Python.

With the speed of compiled Cython, running Python code translated from PHP
using `pyx.php` might be even faster than running the original PHP code in
the same computer.

### Installation

Download from your browser, or from Linux shell:

```
$ wget https://wordpy.com/pyx/pyx.tgz
$ tar xvfpz pyx.tgz
```

Alternatively, you can:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/wordpy/pyx/
```

Currently, `pyx.php` is only available for Python 3.x running 64-bit Linux.
Python 2.x, Mac, or other platforms can be compiled when there are many
requests.

### Quick Start

`$ python # or ipython`

```
>>> import pyx.php as Php; array = Php.array
>>> arr1 = array( (0,'1-0'),('a','1-a'),('b','1-b'),)
>>> arr2 = array( (0,'2-0'),(  1,'2-1'),('b','2-b'),('c','2-c'),)
>>> arr1 + arr2   # same as: Php.array_plus(arr1, arr2), see below
>>> Php.array_merge(arr1, arr2)
```

For more, please see https://wordpy.com/pyx/php/